# Stored procedure problem, runs on local but not on server

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I am having a strange problem with MySQL Stored Procedure.

I have written a simple stored procedure as follows:

```
{

    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE DEFINER=`username`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_create_my_log`(IN source TEXT,
      OUT my_id INT)
    BEGIN
      --
      -- insert record and return primary key
      INSERT INTO my_log (source) VALUES (source);
      SET my_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

      COMMIT;
    END
}
```

This stored procedure is running absolutely fine on my local machine (MySQL Server 5.1, Windows XP). But when I try to run it on the server, I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index of 2 is out of range (1, 0)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement$CallableStatementParamInfo.checkBounds(CallableStatement.java:274)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.checkParameterIndexBounds(CallableStatement.java:710)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.checkIsOutputParam(CallableStatement.java:672)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(CallableStatement.java:1846)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(DelegatingCallableStatement.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(DelegatingCallableStatement.java:95)
    at com.mycomp.myprj.importer.ImporterImpl.onPreLoad(ImporterImpl.java:160)
    at com.mycomp.myprj.importer.csv.FileImporter.load(FileImporter.java:43)
    at com.mycomp.myprj.importer.csv.MyImporter.main(MyImporter.java:82)
0.843 seconds
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: this is Java throwing exception, better show Java code along with these details. SP looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a wild guess (I'm more an Oracle than a MySQL kind of guy):
- Did you perhaps declare your parameter in Java wrong? (my_id is declared as an out parameter in the stored procedure, do the signatures in Java and MySQL match?)
- What happens if you call your procedure from the MySQL command line interface?

Kind regards, Frank

Comment: as I have mentioned in the question, it is running fine on my local machine. Entire database schema is same, Java app is same. Runs fine on local but gives error on server. Also, I tried it from MySQL Workbench command prompt on, it runs fine.

Comment: Found the solution, it was case-sensitivity issue. Windows is case-insensitive, and Linux case-sensitive. :)